# C++: can't static_cast from double* to int*

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

When I try to use a static_cast to cast a double* to an int*, I get the following error:

```
invalid static_cast from type ‘double*’ to type ‘int*’
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        double* p = new double(2);
        int* r;

        r=static_cast<int*>(p);

        std::cout << *r << std::endl;
}
```

I understand that there would be problems converting between a double and an int, but why is there a problem converting between a double* and an int*?

Comment: Not a dupe, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253168/dynamic-cast-in-c/2254183#2254183

Comment: There are other errors in your code, which I've detailed in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473628/why-wont-this-static-cast-in-c-work/2473647#2473647

Comment: If you want to tweak the float's bits this is the wrong way to do it. Use memcpy instead. Otherwise you'll be violating strict aliasing rules and possibly violate alignment, too.

Comment: "Use memcpy instead" - and not to an `int`, rather an `unsigned char[sizeof(double)]`. Or a `uint64_t` if you know that `sizeof(double) == 8` and `CHAR_BIT == 8`, which quite likely you do if you know enough about the implementation to usefully do anything with the bits of a `double`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Aside from being pointers, `double*` and `int*` have nothing in common. You could say the same thing for `Foo*` and `Bar*` pointer types to any dissimilar structures.

`static_cast` means that a pointer of the source type can be *used* as a pointer of the destination type, which requires a subtype relationship.

Answer (score 32):

You should use `reinterpret_cast` for casting pointers, i.e.

```
r = reinterpret_cast<int*>(p);
```

### Of course this makes no sense,

unless you want take a `int`-level look at a `double`! You'll get some weird output and I don't think this is what you intended. If you want to cast the **value** pointed to by `p` to an `int` then,

```
*r = static_cast<int>(*p);
```

Also, `r` is not **allocated** so you can do one of the following:

```
int *r = new int(0);
*r = static_cast<int>(*p);
std::cout << *r << std::endl;
```

Or

```
int r = 0;
r = static_cast<int>(*p);
std::cout << r << std::endl;
```

Comment: More like you /need/ to use reinterpret_cast for pointers... the only valid scenario to use it though is if you have (mostly for technical reasons) a void* which need to cast to a concrete type.

e.g. 3rd parameter of pthread_create() is a function which has 1 argument: a void* which you need to then cast to your structure/etc.

Comment: The world isn't perfect. You're forced to use code from other libraries. And **in that situation** "use reinterpret_cast" **is** a good phrase :)

Comment: There are other cases - for example in OpenCV the images are padded so to traverse `double` images using pointer arithmetic, you need to work at the level of an `unsigned char` to skip the padding to move between rows. So, then accessing the `double` values makes sense if you use `reinterpret_cast`. That's the **only** place I've used them but it has made my code much cleaner.

Comment: "put some information into p before using it!"...
That's what new double(2) does, it initializes the double value to 2.

Comment: Sorry, thought I saw it was `[]`, I've fixed it.

Comment: What's so bad about `r` being unitialized? It's not read before being assigned.

Comment: `Of course this makes no sense, unless you want take a int-level look at a double!` There are *some* valid reasons for this, albeit few and far between :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Answer (score 5):

Floating point-to-integer conversion is supported, so `int a = static_cast<int>(5.2)` is fine.  However, it's a conversion - the underlying data types are completely incompatible.  What you're asking is for the runtime to convert a pointer to an 8-byte structure to a pointer to a 4-byte structure, which it can't do in any meaningful way.

That having been said, if you really want to interpret your double as an integer, `int* r = reinterpret_cast<int*>(p)` will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert between a double and an int with `static_cast<>`, but not between pointers to different types.  You can convert any pointer type to or from `void *` with `static_cast<>`.

The rationale may be that `int *` and `double *` are often effectively arrays, and the implementation doesn't know how big the array is.

Answer (score -1):

Because you used `double *` instead of `double`

The `*` after it means that you are declaring a pointer, which is vastly different from a regular double.

C++ can not safely static_cast a pointer to a different type of pointer like that.

If you are wanting to do this kinda thing, you must first dereference the variable.

```
r=new int(static_cast<int>(*p));
```

You must use `new` because a double and an integer can not reside in the same memory space(sanely)