# reinterpret_cast on a char* pointer

Tags: c++

I had to change the prototype of a function `getData()` which is basically a legacy source code. Upon changing it from returning a `char*` as shown below, I started getting compile errors due to `static_cast`.The question I have is , Is it safe to use `reinterpret_cast`, instead of `static_cast`?

```
  class C1{

     public:

     //void *getData() {return data;} //Legacy implementation*
     char *getData() {return data;}  //My new implementation

     private:
       char data[100];
   };

   int main()
   {
       C1 myobj;   
       unsigned char* begin;

       begin=static_cast<unsigned char*>(myobj.getData());  *//<== This gives compile error.use reinterpret_cast ?*
       return 0;
   }
```

Is there a better solution than reinterpret_cast ?

Comment: why isn't `begin` a `char*`?

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Well that's the way they have it right now ....  They also cast it to  char * or even other different types like a struct etc.

Comment: `main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:31:54: error: invalid static_cast from type 'char*' to type 'unsigned char*'
     begin=static_cast<unsigned char*>(myobj.getData());  //<== Legacy : This gives compile error.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151834/why-cant-i-static-cast-between-char-and-unsigned-char

Comment: @deep_rugs If `getData()` is supposed to return some untyped buffer where the caller determines how it's interpreted, I think you were wrong to change `getData()` to return `char *` and should just change it back to return `void *`.

Answer (score 3):

You can `static_cast` from a `void *` to any pointer type, or between pointers to related types in the sense when one herites from the other.

`reinterpret_cast` is intended to be used between pointers to unrelated types. Is is equivalent to a `static_cast` from first type to `void *` followed with a `static_cast` from `void *` to second type. It T and U are unrelated types:

```
U *u = ...;
T *t;

t = reinterpret_cast<T *>(u);  /* strictly the same as would be
t = static_cast<T *>(static_cast<void *>(u));  */
```

Comment: If you have `int i{}` then `reintrepret_cast<char*>(&i)`. Does the C++ standard guarantee that the resulting address will be the same as `reintrepret_cast<void*>(&i)`  ??

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you want to accomplish. If you want to just use the bitwise representation of `data`, with each element interpreted as `unsigned char`, then `reinterpret_cast` is the way to go.

Your question doesn't give us enough details to figure out if it is "safe" in your case.