# How to properly convert std::string to an integer vector

Tags: c++

My high level goal is to convert any string (can include non-ascii characters) into a vector of integers by converting each character to integer.

I already have a python code snippet for this purpose:

```
bytes = list(text.encode())
```

Now I want to have a C++ equivalent. I tried something like

```
int main() {
  char const* bytes = inputText.c_str();
  long bytesLen = strlen(bytes);
  auto vec = std::vector<long>(bytes, bytes + bytesLen);
  for (auto number : vec) {
      cout << number << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

For an input string like "testΔ", the python code outputs [116, 101, 115, 116, 206, 148].

However C++ code outputs [116, 101, 115, 116, -50, -108].

How should I change the C++ code to make them consistent?

Comment: "I know how to do this in another language" is not a reason to use that language's tag.

Comment: If you are using unicode characters you cannot use `char*` you'll likely want to use wide characters and unicode literals https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c11 for example Python's `str.encode` uses utf-8 by default, so here's an explanation of utf-8 support in C++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403342/how-do-i-properly-use-stdstring-on-utf-8-in-c

Comment: If you're sticking in ASCII space, an unsigned datatype in the vector should help a lot.

Comment: @user4581301 Δ is not in ASCII space.

Comment: True enough. I was watching TV the other night and apparently the aliens built the pyramids. Maybe they are responsible for triangles, too.

Comment: std::vector<unsigned long>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However C++ code outputs [116, 101, 115, 116, -50, -108].

In C++, the `char` type is separate from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`, and it is unspecified whether or not it should be signed.

You thus explicitly want an `unsigned char*`, but the `.c_str` method gives you `char *`, so you need to cast. You will need `reinterpret_cast` or a C-style cast; [`static_cast` will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151834/why-cant-i-static-cast-between-char-and-unsigned-char).

Comment: To be clear: `static_cast` will work on *individual elements*, but not on the pointer.

Comment: thanks Karl. I modified my code and confirmed it's working. Really appreciate your help (as well as the other comments below)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `std::string` contents just fine, no need to convert it to `std::vector`. Try this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::string str = "abc";
    for (auto c : str)
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(c) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

`static_cast` here is needed just because standard `operator<<` outputs `char` as it is, not as a number. Otherwise, you can work with it just like with any other integral type. We cast it to `unsigned int` to ensure that output is strictly positive, for signedness of `char` is implementation-defined.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! My use case actually needs the vecotr<long> explicitly. I added the cout just to help explain my problem

Comment: @ireneisgood you can construct it like this: ```std::vector<unsigned long> result(str.begin(), str.end());```

Answer (score 0):

> How should I change the C++ code to make them consistent?

The difference appears to be that Python uses unsigned char values while `char` is signed in your C++ implementation. One solution: Reinterpret the string as array of `unsigned char`.