# Copy const char* to uint8_t array

Tags: c++, c-strings, reinterpret-cast, static-cast, uint8t

My C-API takes an array of uint8_t's as config parameter. I'm arriving at its doorsteps with a const char*. How do I now copy the chars over to the uint8_t array in the most unproblematic way? Here's what I've got (contrived ofc):

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:16),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Astruct+config%0A%7B%0A++++uint8_t+ssid_%5B32%5D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aauto+set_ssid(const+char*+ssid)+%7B%0A++++config+cfg%3B%0A%0A++++std::strncpy(static_cast%3Cchar*%3E(%26cfg.ssid_),+ssid,+32)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++set_ssid(%22ComeOver%22)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.31070496083551,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:52.689295039164485,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

struct config
{
    uint8_t ssid_[32];
};


auto set_ssid(const char* ssid) {
    // I know this fn has no sideeffects but assume for demonstration
    // purposes that cfg is only initialized here
    config cfg;

    std::strncpy(static_cast<char*>(&cfg.ssid_), ssid, 32);
}

int main()
{
    set_ssid("ComeOver");
}
```

But this doesn't work as none of the pointer is of void* type:

```
<source>:14:18: error: invalid 'static_cast' from type 'uint8_t (*)[32]' {aka 'unsigned char (*)[32]'} to type 'char*'
   14 |     std::strncpy(static_cast<char*>(&cfg.ssid_), ssid, 32);
      |
```

Is it safe to `reinterpret_cast` here?

Comment: `std::strncpy` is C API, you should use some idomatic C++ (`std::copy`?). Note that your `set_ssid` function doesn't have any observable effects, so it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Also I do not like design of this API, also use of it looks like indentation for UB.

Comment: Possible approach: https://godbolt.org/z/78WxaWqG8 as you can see compiler sees there is no side effects in `set_ssid` and removed its code. So please provide code which does something meaningful.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151834/why-cant-i-static-cast-between-char-and-unsigned-char

Comment: @MarekR Thank you, copy_n didn't come to my mind. I know that the function has no sideffects but i zoomed in onto the problematic matter for demonstration purposes and left all baggage out.

Comment: @MarekR That reads out-of-bounds.

Comment: @glades What guarantees are there that the string referred to by the `const char*` pointer fits into the array? What is supposed to happen if it doesn't fit? Is it necessary to pass it by `const char*` or wouldn't it be possible to pass as e.g. array (reference)?

Comment: Also as far as I can tell SSIDs must specify their length explicitly and are allowed to contain null characters, so they cannot be specified as null-terminated byte strings.

Comment: @Marek, using a C API is perfectly fine. ```strncpy()``` is not equivalent to ```copy_n()``` because the former breaks a loop earlier at a null character.(Although it does not ensure a terminating null.)

Comment: @relent95 yes I'm aware that compiler will generate same code. `std::copy` version is more C++ idiomatic. I find this more readable then `strncpy` which needs casting.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes you are right and I was warning about this in first comment (but didn't fix it in example I should) - this UB is a result of shortcoming in API design. Since there is no context what this code should do it is impossible to improve API.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `cfg.ssid_` for the destination buffer instead of `&cfg.ssid_`.
Also you should use `reinterpret_cast` instead of `static_cast`, because `char *` and `unsigned char *`(`uint8_t *`) are not pointer-interconvertible.(It's a rule refining various casts. See [static_cast conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).)

So this is recommended.

```
std::strncpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(cfg.ssid_), ssid, 32);
// Or simply
std::strncpy((char *)(cfg.ssid_), ssid, 32);
```

Comment: I mean, out of possible conversions between pointers to a POD, there are pointer-interconvertible cases and not pointer-interconvertible cases.

Comment: Yes, but all of these conversions go through `void*` anyway. `reinterpret_cast` between pointers is also just a sequence of `static_cast`s through `void*`. The objects here are not pointer-interconvertible, true, but in order for this to work it is important whether the pointer may _alias_ the object (which it may).