# Can I cast an unsigned char* to an unsigned int*?

Tags: c++, memory-management, static-cast

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘unsigned char*’ to type ‘uint32_t* {aka unsigned int*}’
     uint32_t *starti = static_cast<uint32_t*>(&memory[164]);
```

I've allocated an array of chars, and I want to read 4 bytes as a 32bit int, but I get a compiler error.
I know that I can bit shift, like this:

```
(start[0] << 24) + (start[1] << 16) + (start[2] << 8) + start[3];
```

And it will do the same thing, but this is a lot of extra work.

Is it possible to just cast those four bytes as an int somehow?

Comment: Yup. `uint32_t val = *(uint32_t*)((void*)(memory+164));`

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473628/c-cant-static-cast-from-double-to-int?rq=1

Comment: It should be noted that doing this is not very `c++`-y. For example, if 'memory' comes from a file or from the network, you'll need to worry about endianess.

Comment: @mic_e I'm working on a binary translator from pa-risc to x86_64. I'm well aware I have to watch out for endianess :)

Comment: @MadScienceDreams No, please no C-style casts.

Comment: This is called type punning as is actually [illegal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). You can *cast* the pointer via `reinterpret_cast` and it's guaranteed to work. You can't always *dereference* it, though. Your solution with bitshifting is OK and so is `memcpy` to a `uint32_t` object. Recommend you [read this](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html), too.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I understand the hate, but uh...this is C code, this is low-level, bit twiddling, teeth grinding, casting to the devil, assembly-inspecting, code. And we NEED it from time to time, cuz this is often the fastest way to do things. We can wrap the reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*> to make you feel better, but that won't change what we are doing!

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Yes, I’m concerned with explicitness. `reinterpret_cast` is simply much more explicit in what it does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`static_cast` is meant to be used for "well-behaved" casts, such as `double -> int`. 
You must use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
uint32_t *starti = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&memory[164]);
```

Or, if you are up to it, C-style casts:

```
uint32_t *starti = (uint32_t*)&memory[164];
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you *can* convert an `unsigned char*` pointer value to `uint32_t*` (using either a C-style cast or a `reinterpret_cast`) -- but that doesn't mean you can necessarily use the result.

The result of such a conversion might not point to an address that's properly aligned to hold a `uint32_t` object. For example, an `unsigned char*` might point to an odd address; if `uint32_t` requires even alignment, you'll have undefined behavior when you try to dereference the result.

If you can guarantee somehow that the `unsigned char*` *does* point to a properly aligned address, you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I am used to BDS2006 C++ but anyway this should work fine on other compilers too

```
char memory[164];
int *p0,*p1,*p2;
p0=((int*)((void*)(memory)));    // p0 starts from start
p1=((int*)((void*)(memory+64))); // p1 starts from 64th char
p2=((int*)((void*)(&memory[64]))); // p2 starts from 64th char
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reinterpret_cast` as suggested by faranwath but please understand the risk of going that route.

The value of what you get back will be radically different in a little endian system vs a big endian system. Your method will work in both cases.