# Implementation of static_cast operator and it's limits

Tags: c++, static-cast

Could please tell why compiler is not allowing this type cast...Error compiler showing is " Invalid static_cast from float * to int * "

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   float f=45.678;
   float *a;
   a=&f;
   int *d;
   cout<<static_cast<int *>(a);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: can't static\_cast from double\* to int\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473628/c-cant-static-cast-from-double-to-int)

Comment: Why *should* it allow the cast?

Comment: Because casting was meant to allow conversion between different data types...@christian hackl

Comment: need possibly more simpler and deeper explanation @scis

Comment: @virusai: C++-style casts are explicitly designed to allow only *certain* types of casts. That's one of the great things about them; unlike C-style casts, they prevent accidental casts and silent bugs. What's wrong with the answer linked to by Scis?

Comment: Please read this answer which gives a great summary of [what different casts do in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/3848)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should static\_cast, dynamic\_cast, const\_cast and reinterpret\_cast be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Comment: @virusai Casting was meant to allow *sane* conversion between different data types. Converting between`int*` and `float*` will cause problems, therefore not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static_cast` is a cast that makes a compile-time check if the cast is legal.

Consider following examples of when cast is legal:

- casting a smaller-size signed/unsigned integer type to bigger size signed/unsigned integer type with
- upcasting pointer to derived class to pointer to base class.
- and so on.

Casting `float*` to `int*` doesn't make sense from a standpoint of the compiler. If you want to make a such conversion, you should use `reinterpret_cast`.