# C++ how to check if two clsses are from the same object

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, c++11

Encountered this issue while studying for a test, would appericiate a brief explenation.
If I have a `class Object` and another one : `class Point : public Object` 
Now, If I get `Object& O1` and `Object& O2` , but `Object` can be `Point` too... 
So my main question is how can I check if both of them are `Point` Because I need to access a field that `Object` doesnt have

Here are the two classes :

> Class Object { 
>   public : 
>   *some functions* 
>   };
>
> Class Point : Public Object { 
>   double x; 
>   double y; 
>   public: 
>   *same functions different implementation* 
>   };

I wanna access x,y but I need to make sure its a `Point` first.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Object` can never be `Point`. `Object&` can be `Point&` though (and the same with (smart) pointers).

Comment: Is there a way to make sure I'm working on a Point and not on an Object ?
I edited a question, I get Object& O1...

Comment: `dynamic_cast<Point*>(ptr)` what you are looking for...

Comment: usually you don't need to and shouldn't do this. you probably need a virtual method in `Object`. figure out why do you need x,y and give that thing a name.

Comment: related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253168/dynamic-cast-in-c/2254183#2254183

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use dynamic_cast

```
Object &o = ...;
if(Point *p = dynamic_cast<Point*>(&o)) {
  // ...
}
```

If the dynamic type of `o` is a `Point` or derives from it, the code within the `if` will be executed with `p` being readily available (the static type of `o` is `Object`).

If you already know that it is a `Point`, you can use references

```
Point &p = dynamic_cast<Point&>(o);
// ...
```

For this to work, there must at least be one `virtual` function (if only the destructor) in `Object`.

Comment: @NadavPeled not necessarily, if you happen to derive from `Point` again. But that then depends more precisely on what you want to do. Normally it suffices if the object "*is-a* `Point`", and you don't normally want a "*is-a* `Point` but *is-not-a* `SuperGoodPoint`"

Comment: I see, So you're saying that If I know that one part of the equation is a Point, typeid would work, but the more general and correct way to check this out is by using a dynamic cast ?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, if you "need" to know this, you are doing it wrong. There are a few exceptions, but as a rule, you should not need to know which type of object you are "using". Your functions that are different should be declared as `virtual`, so that the code that is doing something with an `Object` can just call the relevant function in `Point` if the object is a `Point` type object.

If you want to access `x` and `y`, your should be doing that indirectly through a virtual function that performs whatever action needs to be done on `x` and `y`. If you really need to touch `x` and `y` when you only have (a reference or pointer to) an `Object`, you are simply at the wrong level.

Comment: Yes, Of Course, as Written above, I'm preparing for a test and it is a part of some "dry" questions about the material where we need to know the behavior of some code..

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on the type information provided by the C++ Standard Library. The following example has been extracted from cppreference.com:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class person
{
  public:

   person(std::string&& n) : _name(n) {}
   virtual const std::string& name() const{ return _name; }

  private:

    std::string _name;
};

class employee : public person
{
   public:

     employee(std::string&& n, std::string&& p) :
         person(std::move(n)), _profession(std::move(p)) {}

     const std::string& profession() const { return _profession; }

   private:

     std::string _profession;
};

void somefunc(const person& p)
{
   if(typeid(employee) == typeid(p))
   {
      std::cout << p.name() << " is an employee ";
      auto& emp = dynamic_cast<const employee&>(p);
      std::cout << "who works in " << emp.profession() << '\n';
   }
}

int main()
{
   employee paul("Paul","Economics");
   somefunc(paul);
}
```

Comment: Uhm, but you can have `class manager: public employee` - is a manager an `employee`? no, but the `manager` has all the properties of an `employee`, but also some extras (e.g. what/who (s)he's manager of), which won't be in an `employee`.

Comment: If manager is not an employee, then it should not inherit from employee (inheritance is meant to model the "is-a" relationship).

Comment: Yes, my point was that a `manager` "is-a" `employee`, but the `typeid(employee)` is not equal to `manager`, so that method is not going to work reliably in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It may be sloppy but if you have a pointer or reference to an object you can always invoke a dynamic_cast. if the pointer is returned as nullptr then you know your object is not a derived class of the desired object.

```
class CBase { 
      virtual void dummy(){}
};
class CDerived: public CBase {
    int a;
};

int main () {
  try {
    CBase * pba = new CDerived;
    CBase * pbb = new CBase;
    CDerived * pd;

    pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pba);
    if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on first type-cast" << endl;

    pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pbb);
    if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on second type-cast" << endl;

  } catch (exception& e) {cout << "Exception: " << e.what();}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "if the pointer is returned as **0**", because dynamic_cast returns 0 when it fails.

Comment: Can you please explain how dynamic cast will fail when trying to cast an Object to a Point ?

Comment: And also explain that this is probably a poor design - yes, there are situations when you REALLY need to do this - but so far in the 10 years since I started using C++ professionally, I have only seen code that does this in a small number of places (3-4 that I can think of).

Comment: @Nadav Peled Think of it like a square and a rectangle. A square is a rectangle but not all Rectangles are Squares. In this case a Point is an Object but not all Objects are Points. so a nullptr would be returned