# array of objects and inheritance

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, inheritance

I have Class A as a base class ,
and Class B , C derived classes from A
and there's class D who have a data member (pointer to Array) of type A (Composition)

```
enter code here

class D{
A **a;
int size;
.......
a = new A*[size]; 
......
 };
```

and  i have Print method , in its body i have to specific element (if it from class B or C ) with a given ID(both B and C have a data member ID ) there should be 2 options in print function .. printing elements for class B , or printing elements for class C  ?
how can i specific the elements ?

i made class A abstract!!

```
enter code here
class A{
.......
virtual void print ()=0;
};

class B :public A{
........
........
void print(){
.......}
};
```

class C :public A{
    ........
    ........
    void print(){
    .......}
    };

```
class D{
........
.......
void Print ()
int P;
cout<<" if you want to print class B elements enter 1 , or 2 for class C"<<endl;
cin>>P;
if(P==1){
dynamic_cast<B*>(*a)->print(); }
else
if (P== 2){
 dynamic_cast<C*>(*a)->print(); }
```

my Question here is how can i specific the elements if it from class B or C ???

Comment: what does you mean by class ID?

Comment: You should really avoid the raw allocation of arrays. Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @richard.g it's a data member in both class B ,C !i should received it from the user then specified it  ( from class B or C)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming a couple of things here, in particular that the `a` member actually contains pointers to subclasses of `A` -- that is, `B`s and `C`s.

I'm also assuming that in the `print` method as you're iterating through this array you don't know which is which.

If you don't care which is which and simply want to print attributes of the object no matter what type they are, then you could provide a pure `virtual` method in `A` which returns a `std::string` (or something) that you want to `print()`, and call that method in your iteration:

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual std::string printMe() const = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  std::string printMe() const { return "I'm a B"; }
};

class C : public A
{
public:
  std::string printMe() const { return "I'm a C"; }
};
```

If you *only* want to print objects of either type `B` or `C`, then you'll need to be able to determine which is which using `dynamic_cast`.  Since using `dynamic_cast` in this way [only works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253168/dynamic-cast-in-c/2254183#2254183) with polymorphic types, you need to ensure that `A` has at least 1 `virtual` function.  However this is OK because, since `A` is being used in an abstract hierarchy, you really should have a `virtual` destructor anyway, and that is enough.

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual ~A() {};
};
```

Now you can use `dynamic_cast`:

```
void A::print()
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    A* theObj = a[i];
    // assuming we only want to print B's...
    B* theB = dynamic_cast <B*> (theObj);
    if (theB)
    {
      theB->printObj();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your class B printMe returns "I'm an A" which is true, but you might mean "I'm a B".
Your class C printMe returns "I'm a B" which is not true and should be "I'm a C"

Comment: @JohnDibling thank u so much , but the print in class A  is "virtual void print ()=0;" , and i override it in B and C , my Question here is how can i specific the elements if it's from class B or C in print of class **D** ??

Comment: @RaiOu:  OK, use my answer simply as a guide to solving your actual problem.