# Calling derived class method from base class pointer

Tags: c++

```
//Parent.h
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

//Child.h
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    virtual void foo(){cout << "inside function foo()" << endl;}
    virtual void bar(){cout << "inside function bar()" << endl;};    
};

int main( int argc, char** argv ){
    Parent* pa = new Child;
    pa->foo();
    pa->bar(); //Error, class Parent have no member bar
    return 0;
}
```

How do i avoid this error other than add those function to the `Parent` class

Comment: You avoid this error by being more careful in your class design in the first place.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253168/dynamic-cast-in-c/2254183#2254183

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare your pointer as Child type. You will still be able to pass it to function expecting a Parent pointer.

Other solution involves using `dynamic_cast<Child>(pa)` although this is often seen as bad design to need this because it defeats what polymorphism is supposed to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use static or dynamic_cast. Example with dynamic_cast:

```
if (Child* child = dynamic_cast<Child*>(pa))
    child->bar();
```

Answer (score 1):

You avoid this error by being more careful in your class design in the first place.

Yes, you can use `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast` to cast a `Base` pointer to a `Derived` pointer if the types are related, as they are here.  But let's think about this.

**Q:** Why do you use polymorphism?
**A:** To provide different behaviour for similar operations, where the behaviour is selected at run-time.

Polymorphism is used to abstract away the *implementation* of an operation from the *provision* of that operation.  All `Shape`s for example have a number of sides.  How many sides depends on the actual shape, but we shouldn't have to know what kind of `Shape` something is in order to ask it how many sides it has.  We should be able to just ask it.

**Q:** Why do you typically need to use `dynamic_cast`?
**A:** Because the base pointer doesn't provide the facilities you need.

If we shouldn't have to care what kind of `Shape` some object is in order to carry out the operations we need on it, then why would the `Shape` interface ever not provide whatever facilities we need?

This happens when we've made a mistake in designing something.  Either `Shape` didn't have enough or the right kinds of facilities in it, or some particular `Shape` subclass is trying to do more than it should.

That's what you've done here.  If it doesn't make sense for `Parent` to have a  (`public`) `bar()` method on it, then it shouldn't make sense for `Child` to have it either.  If it does make sense for `Child` to have a `bar` method on it, then `Child` isn't really a `Parent`, is it?

Maybe `bar` should be a method in some other class.

Answer (score 1):

First we need to know why compiler is complaining !! You will never come to know the reason if anybody tell you the fix. First understand the reason.

You are getting the error during compilation. `vTable` and `vPtr` does not come into picture during `early binding`. It comes into picture in `late binding`. Base class does not have bar method, so compiler is complaining you that the method called by base class in unknown. So you need to typecast it to derived class pointer so that `early binding` gets passed. I hope my understand about the problem is correct. Correct me if I am wrong.