# How can i accsess different parts of my inherited code

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Hi i have a question regarding how to access parts of inherited code.

Say i have this WorldObject that is a base class for alot of other objects. Then i have a class Chest that inherit from WorldObject and also from the abstract class OpenAble, with some methods like open and unlock.

In my main i have a vector of WorldObjects that i iterate through with a for loop. Now to the question, how can i check if a worldobject is also of OpenAble and how can i access the methods in OpenAble.

```
class WorldObject
{
...     //implementation
};

class OpenAble
{
public:
    OpenAble(){}
    virtual ~OpenAble(){}
    virtual void Open() = 0;
    virtual void Unlock(int k) = 0;
};

class Chest : public WorldObject, public OpenAble
{
...  //implementation
};

main()
{
std::vector<WorldObject> objVector;     //vector with several Worldobjects

for (int i =0; i < objVector.Size(); i++)
{
//check if a WorldObject is also of openable
//Do som actions like, open or unlock
//How?
}
};
```

Comment: You can only work with polymorphism when using a container of (smart) pointers.  Then dynamic_cast can be used, even though I would have questions about the design when dynamic_cast is over used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a `dynamic_cast<OpenAble>`. This will throw an error if it is the wrong type though which is relatively expensive given that it is quite likely that the object will be the wrong type.

```
try{
  OpenAble& opener = dynamic_cast<OpenAble&>(worldObj);
} catch (std::bad_cast& ex){
  //not openable
}
```

BTW: As pointed out in the comments below, if you use a pointer to the base class in your container instead of references, then you can (and should) use the pointer version of dynamic_cast which will return a null in the case that your object is not OpenAble. Checking that in your case would be a lot more efficient than throwing and catching exceptions.

I would recommend an entirely different approach though. Inject your base class with an "OpenPolicy".

E.g.

```
class CanOpenPolicy {
public:
  boolean canOpen(){ return true; };
  boolean canClose(){ return true; };
  boolean isOpen(){ return openState; };
  void open(){ openState = OPEN; };
  void close(){ openState = CLOSED; };
}

class NoOpenPolicy {
public:
  boolean canOpen(){ return false; };
  boolean canClose(){ return false; };
  boolean isOpen(){ return CLOSED; };
  void open(){ throw IllegalWorldObjectAction("OpenPolicy disallows operation"); };
  void close(){ throw IllegalWorldObjectAction("OpenPolicy disallows operation"); };
}

//injection via template (no need for base "OpenPolicy" class, maybe some
// obscure error codes at compile though)
// Implicit interface based on how you use the injected policy.
template<OpenPol>
class WorldObject {
private: 
  // CTOR part of the injected contract so you are not tied to knowing how to 
  // build the policy. This is a key benefit over interface based injection.
  OpenPol openPol; 
  ...
public:
  ...
  void open(){
    if(openPol.canOpen()){
      openPol.open();
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

That's not tested or anything. Just to illustrate the idea. You can add multiple policies for different possible operations and the best thing is that you won't need a lot of hierarchies.

To use it just do something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<WorldObject>( new Chest() );
std::unique_ptr<WorldObject>( new Banana() );
std::unique_ptr<WorldObject>( new Chair() );
```

where:

```
class Chest : public WorldObject<CanOpenPolicy> {
   // Very little implementation in here.
   // Most of it is handled in the base class and the injected policies :)
}
class Banana: public WorldObject<CanOpenPolicy> {
}
class Chair : public WorldObject<NoOpenPolicy> {
}
```

Comment: Just a note, dynamic_cast requires RTTI; see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253168/dynamic-cast-and-static-cast-in-c) and the accepted answer.

Comment: @Dennis, Should it not be `dynamic_cast<>OpenAble&>(...)` ?

Comment: The cast would have to be to a reference or pointer. (A pointer cast, with a check for null to see if it succeeded, might be better than a locally-handled exception, in terms of both efficiency and general flappiness.)

Comment: Yeah would be better to use pointers and check, but OP was using references so I thought I should do too. Anyways my real answer is to not use polymorphism like this.

Comment: @utnapistim - Sorry yes. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing, even though you may not like this, is to not throw away type information in the first place.

Collections of generic "object" is a Java'ism, it's not how to do things in C++.

That said, provided the statically known class is polymorphic (has at least one virtual member function), you can use `dynamic_cast` or `typeid`. This functionality is known as **RTTI**, short for *Run Time Type Information*. With some compilers you have to use special options to enable RTTI.

Idiomatic use of `dynamic_cast`:

```
WorldObject* p = ...;
if( auto p_openable = dynamic_cast<OpenAble*>( p ) )
{
    // use p_openable
}
```

Note that `dynamic_cast` to pointer signals failure by returning a nullpointer, while `dynamic_cast` to reference signals failure by throwing an exception, since there are no nullreferences.

Comment: @stefaanv: "software object" isn't a meaningful term in the context of programming.

Comment: @stefaanv: maybe i'm a dullard, but what's an unreal game object, or for that matter, a game object?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think stefaanv means that, for example, the amount of light in a room might be implemented as a class, which could be created as an object on a room by room basis, but that 'light' wouldn't be something you directly interact with etc (beyond the obvious - you see using it)

Comment: i'm not going to answer the nonsense comments above, except to note that the last one falsely attributes a nonsense view to me, before going on with more of the author's nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

The simple (obvious) solution is to use dynamic_cast and cast your objects to `OpenAble`.

The problem with "the simple (obvious) solution" is that usually, use of dynamic_cast shows a lack of flexibility in your class hierarchy and is a symptom of a design problem.

I would offer the OpenAble interface as a set of behavior exposed through a handle:

```
class OpenAble { /* ... */ };

class WorldObject
{
    //implementation
    virtual OpenAble* GetOpener() { return nullptr; }
};

class Chest: public WorldObject {
    struct ChestOpener: public OpenAble {
         Chest *c;
         virtual void Open() {
             // do stuff with c
         }
    };
    std::unique_ptr<OpenAble> chest_opener;
public:
    virtual OpenAble* GetOpener() {
        if(!chest_opener) {
             chest_opener = new ChestOpener{ this };
        }
        return chest_opener.get();
    }
};
```

Client code:

```
std::vector<WorldObject> objVector;     //vector with several Worldobjects

for(auto &obj: objVector)
{
    if(auto openerHandle = obj.GetOpener())
        openerHandle->Open();
}
```