# Can't access derived class method from pointer of type base class

Tags: c++, oop, vector, stl, dynamic-programming

I should specify that I'm a bit new to OOP.
 I'm tying to make a vector of type pointer to Person that has a method GetName() and access a method GetSpg() from my Player class that derives Person. I get an error "GetSpg() is not a member of Person". My question would be: is there any way to access both functions from the vector so that if it points to a Person to not show that method but if it is to do so?

Here is my code:

```
#ifndef _PERSON_H
#define _PERSON_H

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> StrPair;

class Person :private StrPair
{

  public:
    Person(const std::string& fn = "none", const std::string& sn = "none")         :StrPair(fn,sn){};
    virtual void Update(const std::string& fn, const std::string& sn){ StrPair::first = fn; StrPair::second = sn; };
    virtual const StrPair& GetName(){ return (const StrPair&)(*this); };
};
#endif

typedef std::pair<int, int> IntPair;

class Jucator: public Person, private IntPair
{
    std::string tip;
    int spg;
    int average;

  public:
    Jucator(const std::string& fn = "none", const std::string& sn = "none", 
        const std::string& t = "", const int& _spg = 0, const int& _avr = 0, 
        const int& _g = 0, const int& _r = 0) :Person(fn, sn),tip(t),spg(_spg),average(_avr),IntPair(_g,_r){};
    virtual void Update(const std::string& fn, const std::string& sn, const std::string& t, const int& _spg, const int& _avr,
        const int& _g, const int& _r){
    Person::Update(fn, sn); tip = t; spg = _spg; average = _avr; IntPair::first = _g; IntPair::second = _r;
};

virtual const int& GetSpg(){ return spg; };
```

Comment: You can never access derived class methods from base class pointers, but you can do the other way round

Comment: `class Jucator: public Person, private IntPair` where `typedef std::pair<int, int> IntPair`. Inheriting from STL is worst than making a deal with the devil.

Comment: I hope people don't downvote this as being 'too trivial'. I know from experience that a lot of people, especially coming from web technology to C++, find this a tad confusing.

Comment: @Sharadh I'm not sure whare the user is trying to accomplish, is he searching for a vector<Person*> or his own class? Why can't polymorphism help here? I'm confused

Comment: @Marco I'm not sure either, from his code. From what he's saying, however, he needs to cast and use it. 

Polymorphism here (by which I mean having a stub implementation of GetSpg() in person which does nothing) seems contrived. We're polluting the base class with a completely unrelated function in one of the derived classes.

I can't see where the vector OP refers to is being used. If OP can give explanation of his use case, maybe we could do better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't.** 
A pointer of type `Person` can only be used to access data/addresses(functions) that are part of the `Person` object. The compiler simply has no way of knowing what all classes *could be* deriving from `Person` and hence which operations are legal.

Have a look at Dynamic casting. [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cby9kycs.aspx) | [Tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)

In brief:

```
Player* pPlayer = dynamic_cast<Player*>(pPerson);
if (pPlayer) {
  //Use the pointer like a player pointer
  //Note: You can only call player functions from pPlayer, not pPerson
} else {
  //Use the pointer like a person pointer
}
```

Note that this casting is a runtime operation. At compile time, the compiler sees you using the `Player` pointer to access `Player` code, which it is happy to allow!

*Disclaimer: I found your code tough to follow, so consider this an answer to your question in text*

Comment: Dynamic typing/casting can be used only if the base class has at least one virtual function (and in that case it is recommended that the destructor is virtual).

Comment: Agreed - I've never used it without a `virtual` so just learnt this. Please check here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253168/dynamic-cast-and-static-cast-in-c

Thanks @lrineau!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Dynamic casting did the job. I was really confused why I couldn't access that method. The tutorial from cplusplus.com was very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is very similar to the [classic animal/cat/dog example](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson19.html). The basic idea is you have a base class - Animal - and two classes that derive from it - Cat and Dog.

```
class Animal {
    public:
    Animal() {}
    virtual ~Animal() {}
};

class Dog : public Animal {
    public:
    Dog() : Animal() {}

    void bark() { std::cout << "Woof" << std::endl; }

    ~Dog() {}
}

class Cat : public Animal() {
    public:
    Cat() : Animal() {}

    void meow() { std::cout << "Meow" << std::endl; }

    ~Cat() {}
}
```

Now, if you declare a Cat or a Dog object, it's pretty obvious that  you can call either bark() or meow(); but if you declare an Animal object, there's no way of knowing whether it's a Cat or a Dog, so you can't call either method.

In your case, you have Person as the base class and Player as the derived. You may further derive Person and have a new class, NonPlayer, so that Person would play the same role as Animal, and Player and NonPlayer would be Cat and Dog respectively.

If you *really* need to access Player methods from pointers to Person objects, you need to cast the Person* to Player* before. However, you need to be sure before that the pointer inside is a Player*. If it isn't, you'll most likely get a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

There are concepts of upcasting and downcasting which are essential to understand your problem. You can use the concept of dynimc_cast, this [Link](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php) would be helpful to understand.