# Unhandled exception - c++ program stops on cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, subclass, superclass

I have several structs:

```
struct Token
{
 //some content
}

Then follows a bunch of structs that inherit from Token:
struct A : public Token{
 //Stuff
}

.
.
.
struct Z : public Token{
 //Other stuff
}
```

I have a vector std::vector filled with subclasses A through Z and my program crashes when I try to cast any element in the the vector to the subclass. I'm casting by doing the following:

```
A subclass = *((A * ) &vector[0]);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) when downcasting, a [C style cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) is not guaranteed to be safe..

Comment: You cannot possibly have "a vector filled with subclasses". Vectors store elements of one single, fixed type only.

Comment: Probably the vector stores pointers to parent class and the OP is casting the child class pointers before storing them in the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `dynamic_cast` when casting pointers from one type to another in your use case.
The one you are using is a `C style cast` and I strongly suggest you to go with a `dynamic_cast`.
So your code should look something like:

```
if(dynamic_cast<A *>(vector[0]))
    A subclass = *(dynamic_cast<A *>(vector[0]));
```

When a `dynamic_cast` fails it will return a `NULL` pointer and you should take care of it appropriately.
Refer [dynamic_cast and static_cast in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253168/dynamic-cast-and-static-cast-in-c) for more information.
Additionally [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used) will help you understand a lot more types of casts.

Comment: `You should always use dynamic_cast when casting pointers from one type to another.` Not true. _You_ read those posts!

Comment: I meant it in the context of the question only, where dynamic_cast is the correct cast. Do you disagree on that? And BTW what is your problem with me? Do you want to prove me down on the internet? For what? What wrong have I done?

Comment: I have no "problem with you", no. I respond to each post on its own merits, as is right, and this post asserts an "always" rule that is bad advice. I am simply pointing that out. If you only meant _in this case_, then say "in this case", not "always".

Comment: If dynamic_cast fails, you would end up de-referencing a null pointer.

Comment: Whoever downvoted would please care to give some reason?

Comment: With C++11, you can write it like this: `if(A* pointer = dynamic_cast<A*>(vector[0])) { A subclass = *pointer; }` Slightly shorter and less repetitive.

Comment: @Cool_Coder I downvoted it because null pointer check was missing and left an appropriate comment. Now because you edited your answer, I reverted my vote.

Comment: Moreover you don't need a cast (implicit static casting) for casting from Derived class pointer to Base class pointer.

Answer (score 1):

A meaningful usage would be

```
A &subclassref = vector[0]);
```

In above line, no new object is created.

BTW what is the type of your vector and what exactly do you want to achieve? If you store objects of type A to Z in a single vector, it may at some point of time suffer object slicing.

Comment: Thank you. I have a string that i convert into different tokens that all inherit from the superclass Token. I want to parse this and create objects based on the contents of the vector of tokens.

Comment: A token_container class can be prepared using [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) sounds like a better solution. Smart pointer type would be token and it would contains objects of different token sub-class types. Now you can have a `std::vector` of token_container.

Comment: This would be more "meaningful" if the syntax were valid.

Comment: A solution using pointers ended up being a much better idea. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be wrong because I'm making a guess as to how you have filled the `std::vector<>`.

You simply cannot put objects of subclasses into an `std::vector<Base>`. All objects in an `std::vector<Base>` are precisely of type `Base`. If you try something like this:

```
std::vector<Base> myVec;
myVec.push_back(Derived1(...));
```

you first construct an object of class `Derived1` *which is subsequently spliced into an object of class `Base`*, i. e. a new object of class `Base` is copy-constructed from the derived object. Only this copy constructed base class object ends up in the `std::vector<>`.

If you want to have an `std::vector<>` of polymorphic objects, you must use a pointer type as the template argument (and consequently allocate the contained objects with `new`).

Comment: Maybe he is storing pointers to base class in the vector (although the code in the question suggests otherwise).

Comment: @Cool_Coder That's precisely why I put the disclaimer up front. And judging by the fact that your answer was accepted, it seems like I *was* wrong.