# How to cast a shared_ptr<A> to shared_ptr<B> where B is derived from A?

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr

I have a std::list container, holding shared pointers of say class A.
I have another class, say B, that is derived from A.

I currently have code that does this to populate the container:

```
shared_ptr<B> b = shared_ptr<B>(new B);
container.push_back(b)
```

This works fine.

Question is, how can I retrieve the shared_ptr < B > that was initially pushed back to the container?

Doing the following

```
   list<shared_ptr<A> >::iter anIter = myContainer.begin();
   shared_ptr<B> aB = *(anIter);
```

do not compile. I get error

```
Cannot convert 'A * const' to 'B *'
```

Any tips?

Comment: try dynamic pointer cast: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/

Comment: I am not sure, but why not just `shared_ptr<A> b = shared_ptr<A>(new B);` ?

Comment: Anton, the client code needs a B pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast).

You use it like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> basePtr;
std::shared_ptr<Derived> derivedPtr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(basePtr);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But does this not create a shared pointer with an "initial" use count, since a raw basePtr is passed in? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @TotteKarlsson basePtr should be a `shared_ptr`. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I selected this answer because it is straight to the point!

Answer (score 8):

If you know that you've retrieved  a B for sure, as your question suggests, then you can use  **[`static_pointer_cast<>()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/static_pointer_cast/)**:

```
    shared_ptr<B> b = shared_ptr<B>(new B);
    container.push_back(b);
    auto it = container.begin();
    shared_ptr<B> aB = static_pointer_cast<B>(*it);
    aB->showb();
```

If in doubt, you could use **[`dynamic_pointer_cast<>()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/)**.  But as with the traditional `dynamic_cast<>()`, this works **only if your classes are polymorphic**, i.e. you have **at least one virtual function:

```
   container.push_back(make_shared<A>());
   for (auto i = container.begin(); i!=container.end(); i++) {
       shared_ptr<B> spb = dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(*i); 
       if (spb)
           spb->showb();  // at least one virtual function 
       else cout << "the pointer was not to a B"; 
   }
```

The principle is similar to `static_cast<>()` and `dynamic_cast<>()` for normal pointers, see [dynamic_cast and static_cast in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253168/dynamic-cast-and-static-cast-in-c).  By the way,  there's also a `const_pointer_cast<>()` like the `const_cast<>()` for normal pointers.

Here a [live demo](http://ideone.com/ZcYLaF)

Comment: what about polymorphic behavior? this has to be dynamic cast

Comment: Use `static_pointer_cast` if you are 100% sure the object is a `B`, or `dynamic_pointer_cast` if you are not certain.

Comment: This answer should really talk about `dynamic_pointer_cast` and explain de differences between the two

Comment: @Amxx it's difficult in less than 3 minutes to make a full exposé.  The question refers to texamples where the the OP says he populaes with B and wants to retrieve his B.  static_poitner_cast is appropriate in this case.  I'll nevertheless complete.

Comment: @Christophe In the OP's case sure ... but this is a good occasion of building a nice complete answer with long term value ... which is what SE is looking for. Tke that chance to get reputation while teaching things the right way :)

Comment: @Sarang If you're sure of the derived type, are there cases where `static_pointer_cast` won't work (e.g., multiple inheritance, virtual inheritance)? Or were you just mentioning `dynamic_pointer_cast` for the case where you're not sure of the derived type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

some guidance on when to use which cast

Comment: @JamesAdkison: if you are sure then, it works okay- but there are chances when you may not- in such cases you might incorrectly cast between siblings in hierarchy leading to all sorts of undefined behavior

Comment: Yes, I understand the difference between them and why you use one over the other. I just wanted to confirm you weren't making a point about something I didn't know (i.e., a case where `static_cast` doesn't work even when you're sure of the derived type). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. The container do in fact contain various derived objects, so dynamic_pointer_cast is the one to use for me. And I got it working now with the suggestion. I agree that static_cast would be the one to use if knowing exactly what objects are in there.