# How can I convert an ifstream to an istream

Tags: c++, casting, ifstream, istream

Is there any way I can convert an `ifstream` to an `istream`? I have a function called `getToken(istream* br)` that accepts an `istream` as the parameter, but within my `main()` I use an `ifstream` to read a file, and I must use this same `ifstream` to call `getToken`. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: You don't need to it is *already* an `ìstream`

Comment: `ifstream` is derived from `istream`. You should be able to just pass it to `getToken`. What happens when you try? Show a [mcve]

Comment: In addition to Galik's comment, you could `dynamic_cast` it if you really wanted an `istream&` or `istream*`. But its not necessary and adds additional overhead. Also see [dynamic_cast and static_cast in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2253168/608639).

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't need to do anything fancy. The `std::ifstream` type inherits from `std::istream`, so any function that takes an `istream*` can take a pointer to an `ifstream` as input. For example:

```
string getToken(istream* stream) {
    ...
}

ifstream fileStream;
getToken(&fileStream);
```

The streams classes were specifically designed to make operations like this one possible.