# Copy swap idiom - Can we use a dynamic cast operation here?

Tags: c++

I was reading about the copy swap idiom and in an example the swap method was implemented in the following way:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
      public:
      std::string title = "";
      details *detail = nullptr;

      void swap(Derived& lhs, Derived& rhs) 
      {
         using std::swap;
         Base& lb = static_cast<Base&>(lhs); 
         Base& rb = static_cast<Base&>(rhs);
         std::swap(lb,rb);
         std::swap(lhs.title, rhs.title);
         std::swap(lhs.detail, rhs.detail);
      }

      //Regular Contructor
      Derived() { /*...*/ }
      ....
}
```

Now in the swap method is there a special reason that `static_cast` was used.
Will it be safe to use a dynamic cast like this

```
Base* lb = dynamic_cast<Base*>(&lhs)
Base* rb = dynamic_cast<Base*>(&rhs)
std::swap(*lb,*rb);
```

Comment: First, I think your code is wrong, you should replace `base` by `Base &`. Then if you want to use a dynamic_cast, you should write `std::swap(*lb,*rb)` else it doesn't swap the base members. And finally always prefer static_cast over dynamic_cast, because it's done at compile time (dynamic_cast could fail at run-time).

Comment: What does the copy-then-swap idion have to do with your code?

Comment: @OlivierSohn i fixed the typo

Comment: @MistyD what is `base` ?

Comment: @OlivierSohn sorry I meant `Base`

Comment: Ok, now you should probably replace `Base` by `Base&` in the swap method, else I think it doesn't work, because you will swap copies of the objects instead of the objects themselves.

Comment: I agree. Thanks

Comment: @OlivierSohn - You are answering in comments.

Comment: @StoryTeller Well I'm trying to clarify what the question is, the code didn't make sense so now it does :)

Comment: @OlivierSohn - There was nothing lacking in clarity. And your first comment is an answer, plain and simple. The suggestion to prefer static cast goes directly to the heart of the question. Nothing in your suggestion improved the question, it fixed the issues in the OP's code. Those fixes belong in an answer. Where they can be properly voted upon. Especially when you say something unfounded, like `dynamic_cast` happening at runtime here.

Comment: @StoryTeller dynamic_cast always happen at runtime, don't they?

Comment: @OlivierSohn - No. Not always, as the correct accepted answer explains. Only down-casts and side-casts happen at runtime. Up-casts always resolve statically. Otherwise it would be poor design for a language that professes to give you zero-overhead as often as possible.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think you're wrong. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253168/dynamic-cast-and-static-cast-in-c. It happens at runtime. So yes you should prefer static_cast over dynamic_cast in that case.

Comment: @OlivierSohn - OMG, a wrong fact in an answer that is highly voted upon due to popularity! How so very unlike SO.... But seriously. I don't need to read that answer further. I read the C++ standard. [I suggest you do the same](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.dynamic.cast#5). A type doesn't need to be polymprhic for the purpose of up casts (note the "otherwise" in p4). How can non-polymprhic types be up cast then? Statically of course.

Comment: @StoryTeller ok, I was convinced of the opposite, so I learned something today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always `static_cast` to an unambiguous visible base class. `dynamic_cast` is used in the opposite direction - casting from a base class pointer/reference to potentially invalid derived class. It is completely unnecessary here, but yes, it is safe, because it will have the same effect as `static_cast`.

Look at the 3rd point [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

> 3) If `new_type` is a pointer or reference to `Base`, and the type of
>   expression is a pointer or reference to `Derived`, where `Base` is a
>   unique, accessible base class of `Derived`, the result is a pointer or
>   reference to the `Base` class subobject within the `Derived` object
>   pointed or identified by expression. (Note: an implicit cast and
>   `static_cast` can perform this conversion as well.)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. On a side note I have also seen static_cast cast downwards (base to derived) where a dynamic cast would be better since it gives checking. I still get confused most of the times on exactly when to use static_cast so I just stick with dynamic cast

Comment: I disagree : it doesn't have the same effect, as dynamic_cast is done at runtime. the result is the same as static_cast, but the overhead is bigger when using dynamic_cast.

Comment: @MistyD There are cases when you don't want a run-time check, because you *know* that the `static_cast` will succeed. It's like checking vector's size once and then using `operator[]` instead of `at`.

Comment: @OlivierSohn The run-time check happens only when you're truly using `dynamic_cast` above the capabilities of `static_cast`. What you claim does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @LogicStuff indeed, I thought that the rtti type check was done in all cases, but it seems it's not. Thanks for pointing that out!