# Getting an object of a specific derived class, from a vector of base class objects

Tags: c++

Currently I have class `A`, with derived types, `B` and `C`.

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};
```

I then have a vector of type `A`, which I append a single object of types `B` and `C`. Like so:

```
std::vector<A*> list = new std::vector<A*>;
list->push_back(new B);
list->push_back(new C);
```

My main question is: *How would I go about getting an object of a specific type (that inherits from A), from this vector?*

I have attempted to use templates, though this gives unresolved external symbol error

```
template <class T>
T* GetObject()
{
    for (A* object : list)
    {
        if (typeid(*object) == typeid(T)) return object;
    }
    throw std::exception("vector does not have object of that type");
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2253168/4658169

Comment: You could use `dynamic_cast` and check for nullptr. But this seems like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The need to do that is very often a sign that the design could be improved.

Comment: we need an [mre] but presumably your unresolved symbol is due to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that you should read [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `A` a virtual method, such as the destructor (which you should do anyway when writing polymorphic types), and then you can use `dynamic_cast`:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};

...

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> list;
list.push_back(std::unique_ptr<A>(new B));
list.push_back(std::unique_ptr<A>(new C));

...

template <class T>
T& GetObject()
{
    for (auto &object : list)
    {
        T *p = dynamic_cast<T*>(object.get());
        if (p)
            return *p;
    }
    throw std::exception("vector does not have object of that type");
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what I've been implementing for the last hour or so!

Comment: Regarding the return type of GetObject, should it be T& or T*, both appear to work.

Comment: @TomMartin both will work, but since the function can never return a null pointer, a reference may make more sense. It really depends on how the return value will be used by the caller