# C++ Convert static method to simple method

Tags: c++, methods, static

I wrote this.

```cpp
class A {   };

class B : public A
{
public:
    static B Convert(const A &a) { return static_cast<const B&>(a); }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b = B::Convert(a);
}
```

But I would like to have this, do you know how?

```cpp
B b = a.Convert();
```

Thank you in advance for your answers! ^^

Comment: Seems you are being asked to write a constructor for `B` that has `A` as it's argument. Not clear to me what the point of the quuestion is.

Comment: I just want to write this B b = B::Convert(a);
in this form B b = a.Convert();

Comment: That's impossible in valid C++. Since A is a base class of B it's not possible to convert from A to B. Mind you, your existing code is invalid as well.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would say, don't do this. Use `dynamic_cast<B*>(&a)` instead [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253168/dynamic-cast-and-static-cast-in-c#2254183)

But if you can check if a is of type B, you could implement it as follows:

```
class A {
    // ...
    B& Convert() { return return static_cast<B&>(*this); }
}
```

**BUT** be very care full to check if this is even a valid conversion otherwise you might get undefined behaviour during runtime !!!