# How to check if class from vector is a derived class?

Tags: c++

Consider the code:

```
class BaseClass { /* ... */ };
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass { /* ... */ };

std::vector<BaseClass> vClasses;

int main() {

    BaseClass foo1;
    vClasses.push_back(foo1);

    BaseClass foo2;
    vClasses.push_back(foo2);

    DerivedClass bar;
    vClasses.push_back(bar);

    for (BaseClass& el : vClasses)
    {
        if (DerivedClass* d_el = dynamic_cast<CPremiumHero*>(&el)) {

            d_el.CallMethodsFoundInDerivedClass();
        }
        else {

            el.CallDefaultMethods();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I check that one of the elements from the vector is a DerivedClass, then using it further on? The `if (DerivedClass* d_el = dynamic_cast<CPremiumHero*>(&el))` statement throws an error `the operand of a runtime dynamic_cast must have a polymorphic class type` . I don't know what that means, neither do I know what other methods I should use.

Comment: Why are you dynamic casting to `CPremiumHero`?  Why wouldn't you use `DerivedClass` instead?

Comment: Everything in a `std::vector<BaseClass>` is a `BaseClass`, even if it was initialized using a `DerivedClass`. This is known as object slicing. You might want something like a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>>`. `dynamic_cast` also requires your class to have at least one virtual function--usually at the very least the destructor, since without `virtual ~BaseClass();` it's unsafe to destroy a derived class via a pointer to base.

Comment: Also I really doubt most questions along this line are about the "reverse process". There's lots of questions about downcasting and slicing and very few about upcasting.

Comment: @NathanPierson Thanks, Nathan. Some code would me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you haven't defined any virtual function.
Check out this answer to understand the concept.

[dynamic_cast and static_cast in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253168/dynamic-cast-and-static-cast-in-c/2254183#2254183)

Comment: `DerivedClass* d_el = dynamic_cast<CPremiumHero*>(el)` returns nullptr in this case when el should be a DerivedClass.